# Использование Flask с VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, flask

Я создал простой Flask сервер,который содержит 2 html страницы, первая - index.html; вторая - blank.html На первой расположена кнопка для авторизации ВК через [Authorization Code Flow](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user). Вторую я создал для того чтобы указать ее в `redirect_uri`,потому что если я ставлю index.html, он выдает ошибку.

После авторизации в приложении меня перенаправляет на страницу:

> oauth.vk.com/blank.html#code=<код>

Как мне забрать код,который мне передал VK,и перенаправить пользователя который авторизовался снова на index.html?

Код который использует Flask:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def main():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в неправильной ссылка на авторизацию в приложении.

Если вы запускаете сервер Flask, то не забудьте при запуске в консоли к команде `flask run` добавить `--host=0.0.0.0`,что бы получилось:

> flask run --host=0.0.0.0

А ссылка на авторизацию в этом случае должна выглядеть так:

```
<a href=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=<APP_ID>&display=<DISPLAY_TYPE>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/<PAGE_NAME>.html&scope=<SCOPES>&response_type=code&v=5.92><h1>authorize in vk</h1></a>
```